# Non-trivial open dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I recently found the following exercise real analysis:

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be open and dense. Show that
>   $$\mathbb{R}=\{x+y:x,y\in A\}$$

I think it is not too hard to prove. But do we have a non-trivial example of such a set? So my question is:

> Can we find an example of a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ that is open and dense, but $A\neq \mathbb{R}$?

I don't know a lot of examples of dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The rational and irrational numbers are dense, but clearly not open.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

$A = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ works for this purpose, and isn't equal to $\mathbb{R}$. But that's still fairly trivial.

For a less trivial example, fix an enumeration $\{r_n\}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ of rational numbers and a positive number $\epsilon$. Define open intervals

$$\mathcal{O}_n = \left(r_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n + 2}}, r_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n + 2}}\right)$$

and define $\mathcal{O} = \bigcup_n \mathcal{O}_n$. Then $\mathcal{O}$ is an open, dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure at most $\epsilon$.

In fact, we could (by dilating one of our intervals) make the measure of $\mathcal{O}$ equal to any given positive number $\epsilon$.

Comment: What is a real number not in $\mathcal{O}$? How to construct one?

Answer (score 21):

An important non-trivial example is the [middle-thirds Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) $C$: it’s a subset of $\Bbb R$ of cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}=|\Bbb R|$, and since it is closed and nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$, its complement is open and dense. With a fairly small change in the construction one can construct a [‘fat’ Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) that has all of the properties of $C$ that I just mentioned and in addition has positive Lebesgue measure; its complement is again a dense open subset of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 6):

Take $A=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. This clearly open and dense.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove any finite number of points from $\mathbb{R}$ then the remaining set will be open and dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Think a open set $A \in \mathbb{R}$ which is closed under addition. Then what is $A$  in $\mathbb{R}$?