# An example: $U\subset\mathbb{R}$:open, $\bar{U}=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu(U)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lebesgue-measure

I am looking for an example satisfying
$$U\subset\mathbb{R}:{\rm open},\ \bar{U}=\mathbb{R}\ {\rm and}\  \mu(U)=1,$$
where $\bar{U}$ is the closure of $U$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I think [this post with $\epsilon=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/542351/421723) is a very good clue to my question, but sets $\mathcal{O}_n$ are not disjoint and I could not prove $\mu(\mathcal{O})\ge1$.

I appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @N.S. Whoops, never mind!

Comment: What's wrong with taking $U = \mathcal{O}\cup B_r(0)$, where $r > 0$ is chosen such that $\mu(U) = 1$?

Comment: You could also take your dense set with positive but finite measure, then dilate it (linearly) so that the measure becomes 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For a fixed $\epsilon$ define $\mathcal O_{\epsilon}$ the set from that post.

Show that $f(\epsilon) =\mu( \mathcal O_\epsilon)$ is a continuous function.

You already know that $f(1) \leq 1$. Also,

$$f(\epsilon) \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
since the first interval has lenght $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. This shows that $f(2) \geq 1$.

Intermediate value property solves the problem.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much.