# $A\subset\mathbb R$ is open dense, then $\mathbb R=\{x+y\mid x, y\in A\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542344/non-trivial-open-dense-subset-of-mathbbr#) I came up with the problem and here is my progress :

We want to show for any $r\in\mathbb R\exists x\in A\colon r\in x+A$

Define $$\begin{align}f&\colon A\to\mathbb R\\x&\mapsto x+A\end{align}$$

Since $A$ is dense, $f$ can be continuously extended to a function $F\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, with $F\mid_A=f$.

Now for any $r\in\mathbb R$, $F(r)=r+A$

Firstly, $F$ is a bijection :

$$r\leftrightarrow r+A$$

Secondly, $r+A$ is open in $\mathbb R$ as $A$ is open in $\mathbb R$, by continuity of $F$,$F^{-1}(r+A)$ is open in $\mathbb R$. But $F^{-1}(r+A)=r$ which is closed in $\mathbb R$.

By connectedness of $\mathbb R$, $F^{-1}(r+A)=\mathbb R$ that is $F(\mathbb R)=r+A$ for any $r\in\mathbb R$.

So we can restrict $r=x\in A$.

$$\therefore F\colon\mathbb R\to\{x+A\mid x\in A\}=\{x+y\mid x,y\in A\}$$ gives a one-to-one correspondence and we are done.

My question is : Is my approach correct? I would like to know if there are any flaws in my proof.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the title of the question (it should be $x,y \in A$.)

Comment: In the definition of $f$, how is $x+A \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is a **subset** of $\Bbb R$, your function $f$ is not a function from $A$ to $\Bbb R$: it’s a function from $A$ to $\wp(\Bbb R)$ that assigns to each $x\in\Bbb R$ the translate of $A$ by $x$. In order to talk about continuity of $f$, you would first have to define a topology on $\wp(R)$. You can of course extend $f$ to $F$ simply by setting $F(x)=x+A$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$, but this has nothing to do with extending a continuous function. Finally, your $f$ need not be a bijection to begin with, so $F$ certainly need not be one. Suppose that

$$A=\Bbb R\setminus\left\{n+\frac12:n\in\Bbb Z\right\}\,;$$

this is open and dense in $\Bbb R$, and $\Bbb Z\subseteq A$. But $f(n)=n+A=A$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z$.

I very much doubt that any variation of this approach can work. I suggest that you first show that $A+A$ (i.e., $\{x+y:x,y\in A\}$) is open and dense in $\Bbb R^2$. Then for each $r\in\Bbb R$ let $D_r=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x+y=r\}$ and try to show that $D_r\cap(A\times A)\ne\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I =(c-r, c+r)$ be an open interval included in $A$, with $r>0$ and let $z\in {\mathbb R}$. Let $x_n\in A$ be a sequence such that $x_n\to z-c$. When $n$ is large enough, the interval $x_n + I\subset A+A$ contains $z$.

As $z$ is arbitrary, it follows that $A+A = {\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems flawed to me. It is not clear what $x+A$ means in the definition of your function.

First observe that $\Bbb{Q}+ \Bbb{Q}\subseteq \Bbb{Q}$, so that $A$ is open will play an essential rule in a proof.

Without loss of generality, assume $0 \in A$.

Let us show $A+A = \Bbb{R}$ when $A$ is a dense open subset of $\Bbb{R}$. Since $A$ is open, it is a countable union of disjoint open intervals. However, the denseness of $A$ implies that two such intervals always share a same end point. So, we have for example something like

$$A= \dots \cup (-2,-1)\cup (-1,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup \dots$$

We deduce that there is an at most countable collection $\{x_n\}_n \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ with $A = \Bbb{R}\setminus \{x_n\}_n$. Since $0 \in A$, we have $x = a+0$ for $x \in A$. If $x \notin A$, then there is some $n$ with $x= x_n$. The collection $$\{x_n-a: a \in A\}$$ is uncountable, so there is $a \in A$ with $x_n -a \in A$. Then $x_n = a+(x_n-a) \in A+A$. Since $x \in \Bbb{R}$ is arbitrary, we can conclude $\Bbb{R}= A+A.$

Comment: I don't know I may have some misconception, but how do we deduce there is an at most countable collection $\{x_n\}_n\subset\mathbb R$ with $A=\mathbb R\setminus\{x_n\}_n$? Cantor ternary set is closed uncountable nowhere dense, so its complement in $\mathbb R$ is open dense.

Comment: Because we know that $A$ is equal to a union of the form as in my answer. Since this union consists of countably many intervals, only countably many endpoints miss. Does that make sense to you?